# Filter two large text files on CENTOS

Tags: centos, text-files, filtering

I would like to filter 2 large text files over 100 millions of lines; There is an old text file and a new file, and I want to extract only the new added lines. 
For example
old file is:
John
Daniel
Lucas

and new file is:
John
Daniel
Lucas
Chris
Pedro
Carlos

and the result I want is to save only added names
Chris 
Pedro 
Carlos

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: Tried to use 
 comm -23 <(sort fileA <(sort fileB) >fileC 
works on small files. Unfortunately it doesnt on big files, I am getting this error 

/tmp/sortBi65fT: No space left on device

I have 900GB lef on the drive. Not sure how I can fix it .

Comment: root@a15s07 test]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root  901G   17G  839G   2% /
devtmpfs              16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 16G   17M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1            243M  132M   98M  58% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp   976M  2.6M  907M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
[root@a15s07 test]#